# Search Yeoman generator for an angularjs project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I look for a template on the site [Yeoman Generators](http://yeoman.io/generators/) for an Angularjs with Boostraps and NodeJS (Express) and MongoDb but i not found this template. I look for a template on the site ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `angular-fullstack` is the good template.
https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I tried several of the generators and none fitted my needs completely. So I made an empty boilerplate startup project that is tailored to my needs which I use on every new project.